# Cordova PushPlugin not working on Galaxy S2, does work on S3 (same API level)

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

We've build a PhoneGap / Cordova app and use the PushPlugin for handling push notifications.

On the Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.2) everything works fine, we do receive push notifications. However, on the Galaxy S2 (also Android 4.1.2) we don't receive push notifications (although we DO receive the devicetoken).

As both deviced are running the same Android version, they have the same API level. Also because it works on newer (S3) devices, I assume the code is OK.

Here's our AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.APPHQ.APPNAME" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.APPHQ.APPNAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.APPHQ.APPNAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="APPNAME" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.APPHQ.APPNAME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any idea what we need to do to get push notifications working on the S2?

Many thanks!

Robin

Comment: Do u use a custom rom on the s2?

Comment: Phone is out of the box. However, ROM could be customized by the supplier (for example by a TelCo, Vodafone running a custom version).

Comment: @A.S. Any suggestions? Guess you were aiming at something with your question! :)

Comment: Hmm... sorry thought of some missing google services in a custom rom, but you have a real android on your device. I do not have any trouble with the s2 and push notifications. Perhaps you have to check via LogCat wether the onRecive on the s2 is called and the manifest is correct, or your webservice is not calling the second routine to push the s2 or or or. Just try to debug it a more proper way

Comment: In logcat we do see the devicetoken coming in, however push messages are not triggered. They are on newer devices such as the S3 with the same code. Manifest should be correct? This is really strange. :)

Comment: So have a look at your php script perhaps it does not fire correctly, and check the recieves from the gcm server, perhaps it gives you some hints

Comment: It looks like you are using Cordova plugin for the push. I suggest you write a simple native app with push and test it on the problematic device (you can use the code from the [GCM client demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/#demo%2Fapp)). If it works, you'll know the problem is with the plugin.

Comment: I know its old but same problem for me.. not working in some s2 devices (and some works)

Answer (score 0):

You must have checked this but still want to remind you to check below things for GCM to work on the device

1. The device should be configured with one valid gmail account
2. The Android Market (Play store) must be logged in (You should accept the terms and license)
3. The Data connection is properly working

Comment: Checked this, all OK, still not receiving push!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main package is "**com.APPHQ.APPNAME**".
Place your GCMIntentService class inside this package and declare it in manifest file as follows :

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wait. Where? It is already in the manifest, but also needs to be defined somewhere else?

Comment: Add GCMIntentService class in your main package instead of com.plugin.gcm package.